# JPA composite primary key with reference chain

Tags: java, database, jpa

In my DB I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Compilation(
    userId      INTEGER             NOT NULL
        REFERENCES User(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    cTime       DATE                NOT NULL,
    cancelled   BOOLEAN             NOT NULL,
    score       INTEGER UNSIGNED    NOT NULL,
    questId     INTEGER             NOT NULL
        REFERENCES Questionnaire(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY(userId, cTime)
);

CREATE TABLE Answer(
    body        TINYTEXT            NOT NULL,
    qid         INTEGER             NOT NULL
        REFERENCES Question(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    author      INTEGER             NOT NULL,
    cTime       DATE            NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (author, cTime) REFERENCES Compilation(userId, cTime) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (author, cTime, qid)
);
```

Using JPA, I mapped the Compilation entity as follows:

```
class CompilationID implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private int userId;
    
    private Date cTime;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "compilation", schema = "gamifiedmarketing")
@IdClass(CompilationID.class) //alternatively @EmbeddedId
//@NamedQueries
public class Compilation implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User userId;
    
    @Id
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date cTime;
    
    private boolean cancelled;
    
    private int score;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "questId")
    private Questionnaire questId;
    
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Answer.class, mappedBy = "compilation") //JoinColumn is repeatable
    private List<Answer> answers;
}
```

Now, I'm having trouble mapping the other side of the relationship. Should I use Embeddable instead of ClassId? Because in that case I'm not sure that I can reuse it in Answer since I need to add the relationship towards User.

The other class looks like this, I don't know how to add the @ManyToOne annotation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "answer", schema = "gamifiedmarketing")
@IdClass(AnswerID.class)
//@NamedQueries
public class Answer implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    private int author;
    
    @Id
    private Date cTime;
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "qid")
    private Question qid;
    
    @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT", length= 255)
    private String body;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either an `@IdClass` or an `@EmbeddedId`, as both are supported. Since you are already using an `@IdClass` in `Compilation`, here is a way to map `Answer` that also uses an `@IdClass`:

```
public class AnswerID {
    CompilationID compilation; // matches name of attribute and type of Compilation PK
    int question; // matches name of attribute and type of Question PK
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "answer", schema = "gamifiedmarketing")
@IdClass(AnswerID.class)
public class Answer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="author", referencedColumnName="userId"),
        @JoinColumn(name="cTime", referencedColumnName="cTime")
    })
    @ManyToOne
    private Compilation compilation;
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "qid")
    private Question question;
    
    @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT", length= 255)
    private String body;
}
```

These are examples of derived identities; and derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.